# Groovy recursive deep object compare not reporting failures

Tags: recursion, groovy, compare

The answer to this question can be found in this link provided by @bdkosher:
kousenit.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/the-closure-of-no-return

---

I am attempting to write a recursive function that compares to complex objects (JSON objects) and reports on the differences of each.   The code outputs correctly but the failure is not reported as subsequent comparisons take precedent over an earlier failure.

I'm new to groovy so I'm sure there are groovier ways to write it.

The code:

```
public boolean diffObjects(Object left, Object right)
{
    if (left == null || right == null) {
        println "Object comparison failure:  One or both object null."
        return false
    }
    if (left.getClass() != right.getClass()) {
        println "Object comparison failure:  Mismatch object classes."
        return false
    }

    if (isArray(left)) {
        if (left.size() != right.size()) {
            println "Array comparison failure:  Object size mismatch."
            println "Left has " + left.size() + " items.  Right has " + right.size() + " items."
            println "Left Object:"
            println left
            println "Right Object:"
            println right
            return false
        }
        for(int i=0; i < left.size(); i++) {
            // May detect matching items here if sort of objects is problem
            diffObjects(left[i], right[i])
        }
    } else if (isLazyMap(left)) {
        String[] leftKeys = left.keySet()
        String[] rightKeys = right.keySet()
        if (leftKeys != rightKeys) {
            println "Map comparison failure:  Left keys do not match right keys."
            println "Left " + leftKeys.toString()
            println "Right " + rightKeys.toString()
            return false
        }
        leftKeys.each {
            if (isArray(left[it])) {
                // May detect matching items here if sort of objects is problem
                diffObjects( left[it], right[it])
            } else {
                if (isValue(left[it])) {
                    if (left[it].toString() != right[it].toString()) {
                        println "String comparison failure:  Left  " + it + "  value does not match right value."
                        println "Left " + left[it]
                        println "Right " + right[it]
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample data:

```
[
    {
        "productId": "141810",
        "sizes": [
            {
                "sku": "11926",
                "size": "L",
                "gtin": "008206",
                "localizedSize": "L",
                "skuCountryItems": [
                    {
                        "country": "CN",
                        "commodityCode": null,
                        "vat": 17
                    }
                ],
                "available": false
            },
            {
                "sku": "1192",
                "size": "M",
                "gtin": "0082065234",
                "localizedSize": "M",
                "skuCountryItems": [
                    {
                        "country": "CN",
                        "commodityCode": null,
                        "vat": 17
                    }
                ],
                "available": false
            },
            {
                "sku": "1192",
                "size": "S",
                "gtin": "0082065234",
                "localizedSize": "S",
                "skuCountryItems": [
                    {
                        "country": "CN",
                        "commodityCode": null,
                        "vat": 17
                    }
                ],
                "available": false
            },
            {
                "sku": "1192",
                "size": "XL",
                "gtin": "0082065234",
                "localizedSize": "XL",
                "skuCountryItems": [
                    {
                        "country": "CN",
                        "commodityCode": null,
                        "vat": 17
                    }
                ],
                "available": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just from a quick look, returning from a closure (e.g. the one you pass in to the each method) doesn't cause a return from the entire diffObjects method. This blog has some helpful advise: https://kousenit.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/the-closure-of-no-return/

Comment: Change `each` to `every`

Comment: @bdkosher, thank you!    That link explains my error and teaches me some closure.    Skipping the obvious closure joke.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method:

```
def a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def b = ['a', 'z', 'c']

def c = [
    [sku: 'abc', size: 'L'],
    [sku: '123', size: 'S']
]

def d = [
    [sku: 'abc', size: 'L'],
    [sku: 'xyz', size: 'S']
]

use(DiffMixin) {
    assert a.diff(b) == [
        [
            [self:'b', other:'z'], 
            [self:[name:'bytes', value:[98]], other:[name:'bytes', value:[122]]]
        ]
    ]

    println c.diff(d)
}

class DiffMixin {
    static List diff(Object self, Object other) {
        def diffs = []

        if(self != other) {
            diffs << [
                'self': self.toString(),
                'other': other.toString()
            ]
        }

        self.properties.inject(diffs) {list, entry ->
            def key = "$entry.key"

            if(self."$key" != other."$key") {
                list << [
                    'self': [name: key, value: self."$key"],
                    'other': [name: key, value: other."$key"]
                    ]                
            }

            return list
        }        
    }

    static List diff(Collection self, Collection other) {
        ([self] + [other])
            .transpose()
            .inject([]) {list, pair ->
                def diffs = diff(pair[0], pair[1])

                if(diffs) list << diffs

                return list
            }
    }    
}
```

I couldn't get a working assert expression for the c-d comparison. The output looks like this:

```
[[[self:[sku:123, size:S], other:[sku:xyz, size:S]]]]
```

## Explanation

The `DiffMixin` mixin implements comparison methods for the classes you want to compare. I only implemented two, Object and Collection, but it should give you the idea. The Object comparison compares `toString()` output and property values. The Collection comparison basically delegates most of the work, while collecting the diffs. These methods return a list describing the differences.

Think of this as a demo :)